# Cannot create list in evernote

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, evernote

Android 2.3.4 and official Evernote app.

While writing a note I want to add a multiple list (simple, numbered, checked) so I click the corresponding button.

The indicator of the list is displayed (dot, number or checkbox) and I enter the text I want.

At this point, there is no clear way of how to add another item in the same list. If I hit enter it goes to the next line, in the same item of the list. There is no way to add a second item but to fool it by changing list type back and forth (type1->type2). By only doing this trick I am able to see the second list indicator and continue my note.

Example of what I see after enter:

1. Text here...

   and next here...

Example of what I want:

1. Text here..
2. And here...

I am not sure whether I am doing something wrong, if it is a bug (?) or if I have something mis-configured in my keyboard (default international keyboard).

Comment: Have you checked with the evernote forum (http://discussion.evernote.com/) and ask there to see if there's a solution, unless someone here who is already using it, please report here for the benefit of others :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Evernote v4.2.1 and the multiple list functionality works correctly, whether i'm using numbers or boxes or hyphens.

The result is:

1. Test
2. Test

You should try to update your app in Google Play and try again.